# Strange behaviour of fancybox: images displayed off screen

Tags: jquery, fancybox

On an image gallery I built with fancybox I get a strange behaviour: the images are displayed off screen. I.e. the overlay is there but I cannot see any image.

Please have a look at [this site's page.](http://dev.krimitage.ch/archiv/fotoarchiv/bildarchiv-krimitage-2012/)

If you click on a thumbnail in one of the first rows, you won't see any image in the overlay.

If you click on a thumbnail in say the 13th row, you can see the top of the image at the bottom of the screen.

If you click on a thumbnail somwhere around row 17, the image is roughly at the center of the screen.

If you click on a thumbnail around the bottom, you can see the bottom of the image at the top of the screen.

This behaviour is only on my desktop screen. On a android tablet, everything works as expected.

Any hints on what seems to be the problem?

On further inspection of the created css by fancybox I found out that the container for the image seems to be calculated incorrectly:

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-image fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 509px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 2365px; left: 391px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;">
```

Clearly the top position is wrong. But why?

To me it looks as if fancybox doesn't calculate from the height of the screen but from some height derived from the site pages content, which is far higher. But again: why?

Comment: Most likely you applied dimension or transition properties to the `body` tag where the fancybox overlay is appended

Comment: Thanks JFK, this is indeed the case.

But I need this, because I use an off canvas navigation, that pushes the whole body to the left. 

So I must look for a different approach to this kind of navigation.

Comment: @JFK The problem has been fixed by using a supplementary <div> wrapping the whole page between the <body> tags. Thanks again for the hint.